# Hibernate - delete linked entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 2 entites:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="product")
public class Product {
    private Long id;
    private Set<Upgrade> upgrade;

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "products",
                targetEntity = Upgrade.class,
                cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH,
                fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<Upgrade> getUpgrade() {
        return upgrade;
    }

    public void setUpgrade(Set<Upgrade> upgrade) {
        this.upgrade = upgrade;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="upgrade")
public class Upgrade {
    private Long id;
    private Set<Product> products;

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Product.class, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "upgrade_product",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "upgrade_id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="product_id"))
    public Set<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(Set<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
}
```

My data creates these so that a product contains a set of multiple upgrades.

i.e. P1 {U1, U2, U3, U4}
     P2 {U1, U3, U5, U7}

If I delete an upgrade, then everything is fine.  It is just removed from the product.
However, if I delete a product then it attempts to delete all of the linked upgrades.

How do I get this to be able to delete the product and leave the upgrades in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you delete the `Product`, clear its `Set<Upgrade>` and save the `Product`. Something like:

```
public void delete(Product p)
{
    p.setUpgrade(Collections.emptySet());
    entityManager.remove(entityManager.merge(p));
}
```

Comment: merge is only necessary if the product is not already in the persistence context.

Comment: That doesn't explain why it's needed and why it isn't when deleting an upgrade.

Comment: @JB because the `Product` is the parent side of the relationship, so Hibernate sees products as owning updates.

Comment: @Matt: There is no cascade delete on the association, so Hibernate shouldn't delete the upgrades, unless I miss something.

Comment: @JB oh, I completely missed that the OP had actually specified `CascadeType.REFRESH`. Hmm...